# What's the right way to call xcb_connect_to_display_with_auth_info() given a Xauthority file?

Tags: c, xorg, xcb

When I try to establish a XCB connection to a given display stored in a string e.g. `dpy`, I know I can do it in two different ways:

1. Simply call `xcb_connect(dpy, NULL)`, or
2. Set environment variable `DISPLAY` to the value of `dpy` and call `xcb_connect(NULL, NULL)`.

However, if my X server requires a Xauthority file, I can only establish a XCB connection if I set environment `XAUTHORITY` Xauthority file path and then call `xcb_connect(dpy, NULL)`.

I would like to establish this connection without having to set environment variable `XAUTHORITY`. I know there's a funcion in XCB API called `xcb_connect_to_display_with_auth_info()` which receives a `xcb_auth_info_t` struct, but I have absolutely no idea of how to build this struct given a Xauthority file path.

How could I do it?

Comment: Hi, I have the same question. Did you ever figure out how to do this?

Comment: After I wrote most of an answer, I find that it seems the OP alreay found an answer at http://lists.x.org/archives/xorg-devel/2014-October/044324.html

Answer (score 0):

The contents of a `xcb_auth_info_t` struct are the same as the parameters to `XSetAuthorization`.

Unfortunately, that's not well documented either.

name is the authorization method name (e.g. "MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1"), and data is the authentication data (e.g. a 128-bit cookie).

If you want to avoid using the `XAUTHORITY` env var, but have an .Xauthority file, I think you could use `XauReadAuth` to parse the .Xauthority file and locate the entry corresponding to the display you are connecting to, and extract the authentication method and data.